# Why is data.posts undefined when accessing using subscriber method in redux?

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux

## How can I access complete state in redux?

```js
const { createStore } = require("redux");

const initialState = {
  posts: [
    { id: 1, title: "Post one" },
    { id: 2, title: "Post two" },
  ],
};
```

My Posts Reducer

```js
const PostsReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "add_post":
      return {
        ...state,
        posts: [...state.posts, action.payload],
      };

    case "delete_post":
      return {
        ...state,
        posts: state.posts.filter((post) => post.id !== action.payload),
      };

    case "get_all_posts":
      return state.posts;

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const store = createStore(PostsReducer);
```

My Action Creators:

```js
const GetAllPosts = () => {
  return {
    type: "get_all_posts",
  };
};

const AddPost = (payload) => {
  return { type: "add_post", payload };
};

const removePost = (payload) => {
  return { type: "delete_post", payload };
};
```

Accessing Store data:

```js
store.subscribe(() => {
  const data = store.getState();
  console.log(data.posts);
});

store.dispatch(GetAllPosts());
```

While I am console logging `data.posts` it returns `undefined`.

I am accessing using subscriber method:

```js
store.subscribe(() => {
  const data = store.getState();
  console.log(data.posts);
});

store.dispatch(GetAllPosts());
```

Note:

I am Using Redux(4.2.1)

By using `GetAllPosts()`, I am able to access data, but I cannot get `data.posts` in console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `get_all_posts` case is returning the `state.posts` array directly instead of setting a state object with a `posts` property.

```js
case "get_all_posts":
  return state.posts; // <-- just the posts array
```

Update `get_all_posts` case to return the correct state invariant, likely the initial state value with all the posts included.

Example:

```js
const initialState = {
  posts: [
    { id: 1, title: "Post one" },
    { id: 2, title: "Post two" },
  ],
};

const PostsReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "add_post":
      return {
        ...state,
        posts: [...state.posts, action.payload],
      };

    case "delete_post":
      return {
        ...state,
        posts: state.posts.filter((post) => post.id !== action.payload),
      };

    case "get_all_posts":
      return { ...initialState };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Comment: HI Thank you for your reply, Also when i am accessing data through subscriber method, i am getting undefined.

store.subscribe(() => {
  const data = store.getState();
  console.log(data.posts);
});

Why?

Comment: @SairamGudiputi `data.posts` is *still* undefined after fixing the reducer case? `data.posts` should be defined since it's the initial state value. If it's not too much trouble do you think you could create a ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces the issue you see that we could inspect live?